# Accessing vendor-specific CSS properties w/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am curious how one would access/modify properties like `-moz-transition` (or any property from [this list](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/)) by means of native javascript i.e. without relying on jQuery's `.css('property', 'value');`

For instance, to change an element's `background-color` one would work with `element.style.backgroundColor`.

Do vendor-specific property names just get camelCased and become operable? I couldn't do so, maybe they are no longer represented by properties of `style` and should be modified elsewhere? Or maybe they are not accessible through DOM at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use upper camel case, e.g., `el.style.MozTransition`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/R3y6f/1/

Comment: Amazing! I was camel-casing it as `mozTransition` instead, was there some documentation that pointed you to capitalizing the first letter of the property? I never could find any

Comment: Be aware that Microsoft does it differently.

Answer (score 2):

ex: -webkit-box-shadow

```
.style.setProperty("-webkit-box-shadow", "0 0 7px #ccc", null);
.style.removeProperty("-webkit-box-shadow");
.style["-webkit-box-shadow"];
```

Comment: Does this imply that they are not accessible as DOM element properties?

Comment: they are style properties, not element properties ;)

Comment: I get lost in semantics thinking of `style` being a complex element property, kind of confirmed by `.style['property']` notation. Which is pretty neat, TIL, +1!