# CSS/JS/HTML: JS Function to rotate full page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation

Okay, so for my final in a web class, we are just supposed to make a website do whatever we went. I'm done now and decided to add some fun stuff.

I want to use [`-webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg)`](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/); on the body.

How can I do that in a javascript function? I have done it with the body background before, but I cannot get this to work.

Here is what I tried:

```
function rotatepage() {
    document.body.style.-webkit-transform =  rotate(-90deg); 
}
```

and

```
function rotatepage() {
    document.body.style =  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg); 
}
```

Any ideas? Is this possible?

Comment: I think this question is duplicated. find out here may can help you with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708895/how-to-set-the-style-webkit-transform-dynamically-using-javascript

Comment: Meh, why does nobody see obvious syntax errors anymore nowadays?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the style -webkit-transform dynamically using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708895/how-to-set-the-style-webkit-transform-dynamically-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

[Today I learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729620/accessing-vendor-specific-css-properties-w-javascript):

```
document.body.style.setProperty("-webkit-transform", "rotate(-90deg)", null);
```

[Fiddle'd](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/vvWUt/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to experiment in whatever browser you're using, but I found that the styles were named such that I needed to change `document.body.style.MozTransform="rotate(4deg)"`, which means there's a fair chance you need to be changing `document.body.style.WebkitTransform =  rotate(-90deg);`

Remember, javascript very much doesn't like things like `'-'` in variable names...