# Escaping hyphen on javascript's getElementbyId

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to pass -webkit-background-clip property with javascript.

Because of the hyphen at start, I cant seem to get it right.
Tried it with [, ", ' etc. 
How do I escape dash?

```
document.getElementById("menu").style.-webkit-background-clip = "text";
```

Comment: Yea but its just one element, thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing vendor-specific CSS properties w/JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729620/accessing-vendor-specific-css-properties-w-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bracket notation...

```
document.getElementById("menu").style["-webkit-background-clip"]
```

...or use camel case...

```
document.getElementById("menu").style.webkitBackgroundClip
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQ3nR/).

Note that JavaScript resolves these to different names, but the browser supports both.

Comment: Tried that, didnot work! Chrome's console says: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment!

Comment: @NabRaj That doesn't sound related to the code you posted. Sounds more like you attempted to do assignment to a constant.

Comment: yea, every line with hyphen(background-color etc) was throwing error. Using DOM(camel case) worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @Nab: I believe you miss quotation marks in the hyphen solution and the engine things you are trying to do a subtraction. The error you mentioned would not be generated by `document.getElementById("menu").style["-webkit-background-clip"]`.

Answer (score 1):

try
`document.getElementById("menu").style["-webkit-background-clip"] = "text";`

Comment: From chrome's console: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment